# Isomorphic invariances between objects, and categories

Tags: category-theory

I am studying Category Theory on my own and find many examples and proofs use the fact that certain properties are invariant among all isomorphic objects within a given category.  However, many such invariances are used without any prior exposition or proof - as if “everybody knows” which properties are isomorphic invariant.

Could anyone please enumerate the most useful invariant properties for isomorphic objects within a given category?

Since many objects such as posets and groups can also be viewed as self-contained categories, it would also be great to have a list of the most useful invariances of isomorphic categories.

Thanks

Comment: Could you give a specific example of an example or proof that is causing you problems, please. Your question is far too broad to be answered as it stands.

Comment: A central thesis of category theory is that every meaningful property of a mathematical object is isomorphism invariant.

Comment: In my opinion, if you have a property that isn't shared by isomorphic objects, you've failed to model your situation properly. E.g. what you are interested in is not a category $\mathcal{C}$, but instead a category $\mathcal{C}$ together with a set $S$ and an essentially-surjective-on-objects functor $S \to \mathcal{C}$.

Comment: As an aside, *equivalence* of categories is a more generally useful notion than *isomorphism*. Setoids, preorders, and connected groupoids are often more useful notions to consider than sets, posets, and groups respectively; e.g. a category is equivalent to a poset  if and only if it is a preorder.

Comment: My question is simpler than even these comments imply.  In brief, my question is: “What properties are known to be isomorphic invariant among objects in any category?” (Since an exhaustive list would be too much to ask, I would be happy with an enumeration of the most useful such properties - and I’m not asking for proofs.)

Comment: For example, in example 2.13 in Awodey p.37, he proves two posets are Not isomorphic by showing that the number of generalized elements from a particular set is not the same for the two posets - thus violating an isomorphic invariant property.  However, how does one learn of such invariant properties??  (They are often used without ever being proved, or even previously cited.)

Comment: @MPitts: Applying any functor to an isomorphism gives an isomorphism. A great many (most? all?) "invariants" are simply the values you get by applying a functor. The example you describe sounds like applying a functor $\hom(X, -) : \mathcal{C} \to \mathbf{Set}$ where $X$ is a fixed object of $\mathcal{C}$, and then observing that two values of this functor are not isomorphic sets.